# Alternative to Max If with formulaArray

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a worksheet with the following info:

```
|    A    |    B    |    C    |
|   10    |   cat   |         |
|   15    |   cat   |         |
|    5    |   dog   |         |
|    4    |   dog   |         |
|   11    |   dog   |         |
|    6    |  fish   |         |
|   10    |  fish   |         |
```

I want to find out which is the maximum value in the A column by grouping them according to the value into the B column. That is, the max value for cat, for dog and for fish.

I was thinking about using the function `FormulaArray` with `Max` and `If` functions:

```
mysheet.range("C1:C7").FormulaArray="=Max(If(R1C2:R7C2=RC[-1],R1C1:R7C1))"
```

i tested it but it doesnt work, this formula only compares the first element (B1) with the whole range (B1:B7).

Is there any better answer?

Comment: why not directly `mysheet.range("C1:C7").Formula="=SUMPRODUCT(Max((R1C2:R7C2=RC[-1])*R1C1:R7C1))"?
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of `MAX` and `INDEX` like this:

[image]

Comment: Or without the `INDEX` as an array formula: `=MAX(($B$1:$B$7=B1)*$A$1:$A$7)`

Comment: If it's an array formula, it will fail with OP's current implementation. See my answer.

Comment: @JMcD - thanks, I was providing an alternative to array formula-based answer; I think OP would prefer array formula though, per the question.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie - Both of our answers would work. It's good to put options out there. I was pointing out to Alexis why an array formula wouldn't work without a code adjustment like I suggested.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I tried this for the minimum value `=MIN(INDEX(($B$1:$B$7=B1)*$A$1:$A$7,0))` apparently it doesn't work (calculates zero for all the cells)

Answer (score 0):

Array formulas can return single results or multiple results. You want yours to return a single result for each cell in your range, but since you're applying the array formula to the entire range, it is being interpreted as a single formula returning multiple results over the entire range instead of a single formula for each cell.

You can test this by changing something in your array range. Say, change the ",0)" to ",1)" in C3. It will tell you you can't change a part of an array. They're all connected.

What you need to do is loop through the cells in your range and apply the formula to each of them.

```
Dim r As Range
Dim rFormulas As Range
Set rFormulas = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C8")
For Each r In rFormulas.Cells
  r.FormulaArray = "=MAX(IF(R2C2:R8C2=RC2,R2C1:R8C1,0))"
Next r
```

Comment: that's correct, but since i got a loop inside other loop with 2000 rows per sheet i need a quick way to do it.